# Recursive dereferencing in a template typelist, how to return the correct type

Tags: c++, templates, template-meta-programming

I'm new to template-meta-programming and trying to do the first steps with help of Nicolas Brailovsky's blog.

I created the following scenario:

```
TEST(Check_NthInstance)
{
    typedef Lst< char, Lst< int>> a;  // a list of types
    Instances<a> inst; //Holds an instance value for each type

    char&   ref1 = NthInstance<a, 0>::get(inst);    
    ref1 = 'x'; //can easily manipulate an instance depending on the type

    int& ref2 = NthInstance<a, 1>::get(inst); //here we get a compile error
}
```

In the scenario, I'm trying to get a reference to the instance value in

```
Instances<a> inst;
```

by index.

The needed declarations are here:

```
struct NIL 
{
    typedef NIL Head;
    typedef NIL Tail;
};

template <typename H, typename T=NIL> struct Lst 
{
    typedef H Head;
    typedef T Tail;
};

template <typename LST> struct Instances 
{
    typedef typename LST::Head Elm;
    Elm instance;
    Instances<typename LST::Tail> next;
};
template <> struct Instances<NIL> {};

template <typename TypeLst, int N> struct NthInstance 
{
    typedef typename TypeLst::Tail TypeNext;
    typedef typename NthInstance<TypeLst, N-1>::NthInstanceType NthInstanceType;

    template <typename InstancesLst> 
    static NthInstanceType& get(InstancesLst &instances_lst) 
    {
        return NthInstance::get(instances_lst.next);
    }
};

template <typename TypeLst> struct NthInstance<TypeLst, 0> 
{
    typedef typename TypeLst::Head NthInstanceType;

    template <typename InstancesLst>
    static NthInstanceType& get(InstancesLst &instances_lst) 
    {
        return instances_lst.instance;
    }
};
```

I suppose, the problem is the recursive deduction in this line:

```
return NthInstance::get(instances_lst.next);
```

Compiler message (VS2010) doesn't really help:

```
1>...\empty.cpp(59): error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'char' to 'int &'
```

I also found out, that my type dereferencing is not working as expected:

```
NthInstance<a,0>::NthInstanceType
```

Should differ from

```
NthInstance<a,1>::NthInstanceType
```

The question is, how to write it correctly?

Please provide a non c++11 example, if possible.

Comment: Please post your compiler error.

Comment: You definitely miss `return NthInstance<TypeLst, N-1>::get(instance_lst.next);` there.

Comment: @erenon: Tried it, makes no difference. I'm curious, if it's the NthInstanceType definition.

Comment: @erenon: Your answer was almost correct. I needed `return NthInstance<TypeLst::Tail, N-1>::get(instance_lst.next)` and additionally had to correct the NthInstanceType typedef.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You probably wanted to do something like this:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Nil { };

template <class Type, class Next = Nil>
struct Lst {
   typedef Type ValueType;
   typedef Next NextType;
   Type value;
   Next next;
};

template <int N, class L>
struct GetterType:GetterType<N-1, typename L::NextType> { };

template <class L>
struct GetterType<0, L> {
   typedef typename L::ValueType ValueType;
};

template <int I>
struct Getter {
   template <class L>
   static typename GetterType<I, L>::ValueType& get(L &lst) {
      return Getter<I-1>::get(lst.next);
   }
};

template <>
struct Getter<0> {
   template <class L>
   static typename GetterType<0, L>::ValueType& get(L &lst) {
      return lst.value;
   }
};

int main() {
   Lst<char, Lst<int> > lst;
   Getter<1>::get(lst) = 10;
   Getter<0>::get(lst) = 'a';
   std::cout << Getter<0>::get(lst) << std::endl;
   std::cout << Getter<1>::get(lst) << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: Your solution works fine and is expandable to my needs. Can you please explain the trick in this line: template <int N, class L>
struct GetterType:GetterType<N-1, typename L::NextType> { }; Is this a recursive class hierarchy ?

Comment: This is recursive "query" to gain a type of Getter::get result. To explain it more briefly: to answer what will be the result of get we need a type of a list node - `L` and the number of iteration we need to go through to reach the type we are interested in - `N`. The only way to each recursive step bring us closer to the result type is to call `GetterType<N-1, typename L::NextType>` i.e. with decreased index and type of a next list node. Inheritance could be successfully replaced with inner `typedef GetterType<N-1, typename L::NextType>::ValueType ValueType` but save us some code :)

Comment: Yeah, in my code I used the typedef solution. In your example I learned, that recursive inheritance works too.  Very nice. :))

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure this line is correct?

```
typedef Lst< char, Lst< int>> a;  // a list of types
```

in pre-C++11 it should be

```
typedef Lst<char, Lst<int> > a;  // a list of types
```

Comment: It's correct, at least for VS2010, which has no problem with the template closing parentheses